# Electrical field in a circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-fields

This is a picture I found online:

[image]

I have two questions about this.

1. How do we know that over the power source and over the resistor, the electrical field is parallell to the power source or resistor. I highlighted this with the blue circles.
2. Is the field symmetric around the power source and resistor if we rotate around it?

Comment: It is not a very accurate diagram. And also these diagrams are formed using maxwell equations(which means pure maths(numerical)).

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is supposed to **illustrate** the electric field and nothing more.
Given that the positive terminal of the cell has an excess of positive charges and the negative terminal has an excess of negative charges the diagram shows how an electric field line might go from the positive terminal to the negative terminal, nothing more.
Note that the circuit components are modeled as *lumped-elements*, a simplified representation of a physical circuit that assumes all components are concentrated at a single "point" so the real field patterns are much more complex and exist in three dimension not the two dimensions shown in your diagram.

Answer (score 0):

This is a schematic diagram. Schematic diagrams are *schematic* not physical. They don't tell you anything about the physical shape or arrangement of the devices or wires, except possibly in a very abstract way. So the field lines indicated can also only be indicative and not physical.

One obvious non-physical feature in the drawing is that some of the field lines are shown intersecting the wires at an angle, where in the physical world, the electric field will always be normal to the surface of a good conductor.